# MySQL: Remove rows from a GROUP BY result if it only grouped 1 row

Tags: mysql

When selecting data, I'm able to show how many rows were grouped from using `GROUP BY` by running:

```
SELECT id, created, COUNT(id) `count` FROM table
    GROUP BY id
    LIMIT 0,30
```

The `count` field easily outputs how many rows were affected by the `GROUP BY`. In MySQL is it possible to automatically *not* include any row which only has a `count` value of `1`?

Comment: Well if id has an PRIMARY/UNIQUE KEY.. GROUP BY id is pretty redundantly useless (based on the missing create table statement)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a `HAVING` clause which lets you add conditions after the grouping has been done.

```
SELECT id, created, COUNT(id) cnt FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING cnt > 1
LIMIT 0,30
```

Another thing to mention is that the grouping might not be correct. If you group by `id` and you select `id, created` then the value for `created` is undetermined. MySQL will choose any of them for a given `id` if they differ. You might be interested in grouping by that field too or applying an aggregate function (eg: `max(created)`).

A second thing to mention is that `COUNT(id)` won't count the amount of rows but rather the amount of rows that have `id` not null. If `id` is never null then it would result in the same value as doing `count(*)`.

Comment: +1 Mosty Mostacho for mentioning is the non aggregate column "created"... @enchance you should really read what impact will have see http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: I agree on your points on `created` and using `COUNT(id)` but this was just a sample query I used to keep things clear.

Comment: @enchance Yes, check it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e6b0e/2). But next time create a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `HAVING` to limit the results of an aggregate function like COUNT (MAX,MIN,SUM, etc).

```
SELECT id, created, COUNT(id) `count` 
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
LIMIT 0,30
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the manual and find HAVING

```
... HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/select.htmlhavinh